# Distancia entre LineString y punto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente LineString

```
Line =  [(-58.39323087479187, -34.64522852285068), (-58.39493519860744, -34.64593911202303), (-58.39540370387294, -34.64612018963881), (-58.39577715270643, -34.64624297063709), (-58.3961720086682, -34.64636735300267), (-58.39657393244798, -34.64649079664271), (-58.39686900560828, -34.64658786576401), (-58.39768408267521, -34.64688376919202), (-58.39804117638568, -34.64699057960223), (-58.39811749931905, -34.64700849164973), (-58.39828903137601, -34.64704378391358), (-58.39848415993365, -34.64708122410398), (-58.3986547387477, -34.64709449060737), (-58.3988514934597, -34.64709955836587), (-58.39897325079004, -34.6471023653607), (-58.39913887311855, -34.64708744614302), (-58.40078230339798, -34.64694668280777), (-58.4011366548087, -34.64692373544752), (-58.40140137506319, -34.64690660901691), (-58.40169294994597, -34.64689298223946), (-58.40188791399491, -34.64691373562576), (-58.40216794959328, -34.64695369573664), (-58.41441599275006, -34.64898345419851), (-58.41468645364731, -34.64902341675737), (-58.41491789917437, -34.6490522244158), (-58.41504783372419, -34.64906712767555), (-58.41517069354625, -34.64908171429391), (-58.41533660567228, -34.64909137548982), (-58.41610344894117, -34.64910924442286), (-58.41663883920926, -34.64911070715178), (-58.41691994816962, -34.64910623905278), (-58.41712925394172, -34.64908282123896), (-58.41735140092969, -34.64905175937751), (-58.4175040105956, -34.64901464682342), (-58.41778163827102, -34.64893890857992), (-58.41810776345819, -34.64882463807892), (-58.42014859446244, -34.64801074189261), (-58.42109129459963, -34.64768468167974), (-58.42150738131538, -34.64755870865789), (-58.42342555778116, -34.64704856595483), (-58.42380036444368, -34.64696522849173), (-58.42402399498763, -34.64692538456899), (-58.42422994553617, -34.64689682578112), (-58.42442882836995, -34.64688048716456), (-58.42466544132492, -34.64686749516407), (-58.42492895224804, -34.64686969903472), (-58.42519118859626, -34.64689581060387), (-58.42548633816839, -34.64693076251233), (-58.42574834123136, -34.64696690278817), (-58.42600734692162, -34.64703299983701), (-58.42633487929256, -34.64713342399471), (-58.42672363380665, -34.6472903832091), (-58.42701863504796, -34.64744017525714), (-58.42735477118806, -34.64764714102999), (-58.42758954729708, -34.64780944247776), (-58.42780426987807, -34.64798874926387), (-58.42805931284784, -34.64825160891823), (-58.42826384085686, -34.64851328718624), (-58.42836837245316, -34.64865441916345), (-58.42849097552769, -34.64886100909527), (-58.42863862000018, -34.64921981114054), (-58.43039902344795, -34.65411150588781), (-58.43058099211167, -34.65454759092934), (-58.43074440690579, -34.65487960245804), (-58.43091147516467, -34.65519055733962), (-58.43112803380347, -34.65554914847827), (-58.43260609566938, -34.65801519415205), (-58.43278567440816, -34.65827265019357), (-58.43296016110701, -34.65845540315134), (-58.43315011877778, -34.65865061801186), (-58.43335842356506, -34.65885169235345), (-58.43349821535271, -34.65894935913921), (-58.43369231539262, -34.65907745659961), (-58.43391244522258, -34.65921105679707), (-58.4342196854351, -34.65939138210857), (-58.43446159367213, -34.65950262175289), (-58.4354319679709, -34.65989668701516), (-58.44002778106239, -34.66183363815986), (-58.44218397209216, -34.66275027310008), (-58.46163757545956, -34.67090968101208), (-58.46246050330255, -34.67120817614321), (-58.46280547898094, -34.67132107658005), (-58.46307488578911, -34.67139608443851), (-58.46332241010779, -34.67144991252323), (-58.46353300409209, -34.67149541798045), (-58.46859653017688, -34.67249959570204), (-58.46908781436287, -34.67259411624501), (-58.46938034898276, -34.67267684368898), (-58.46981999535013, -34.67282189408634), (-58.47017709131737, -34.67296547046871), (-58.47422872212128, -34.67473003403723), (-58.47458907678709, -34.67490463353656), (-58.47485536868304, -34.67507001487545), (-58.47511721636123, -34.67527809815956), (-58.47561611823835, -34.67573966172805), (-58.47637678148585, -34.67650147966764), (-58.4772898411353, -34.677473083393), (-58.47756878106423, -34.67779366716631), (-58.47927838887487, -34.68008637250686), (-58.4796189824651, -34.68046368453628), (-58.4797836819284, -34.68061589623475), (-58.47997298162954, -34.68077149644261), (-58.48013854950542, -34.68087214089938), (-58.48033951807771, -34.68099482470753), (-58.48077178430249, -34.68117907983302), (-58.4809809942354, -34.68125468946911), (-58.48151812211091, -34.68141121492266), (-58.49074865351113, -34.68364996209967), (-58.49280644305118, -34.68416717487745), (-58.49323181266317, -34.68430677581161), (-58.4939040130434, -34.68450404480966), (-58.494446444632, -34.68469758388901), (-58.50679022633284, -34.68987115611775), (-58.50863040256832, -34.6906581855909), (-58.51021336002367, -34.69130911057548), (-58.51092048468821, -34.69162906732615), (-58.51128148474532, -34.69180116103016), (-58.51164513166684, -34.69197626961216), (-58.51190552938787, -34.6921423269721), (-58.51223224913973, -34.6923465503359), (-58.51266317587315, -34.69263696928233), (-58.51283797439013, -34.69275574911642), (-58.51343928772994, -34.69323891435921), (-58.51613617076313, -34.69565149779803), (-58.51639524277449, -34.6959621229764), (-58.51657880735801, -34.69623621532357), (-58.51668736518741, -34.69648714304233), (-58.51677990482248, -34.69677220564932), (-58.51681912473175, -34.69694815217243), (-58.51683540541565, -34.69728978685934), (-58.51682586767205, -34.69757721116119), (-58.51679226699013, -34.697818097686), (-58.51670205772855, -34.69812198637412), (-58.51657448656194, -34.69837726193614), (-58.51643210417134, -34.69861385564264), (-58.51621815101113, -34.69887195886386), (-58.5160233966457, -34.69905049204797), (-58.51546229204164, -34.69948099921363), (-58.51164101129704, -34.70237114559549)]
```

y tengo este punto

```
Punto = (-58.503015,-34.704488)
```

Si aplico el siguiente codigo

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, LinearRing

p = Point(Punto)
linea=LineString(line)
line1 = list(linea.coords)
print(linea.project(p))

np = linea.interpolate(linea.project(p))
a = p.distance(linea)
print(np)
print(a)
```

Obtengo que el punto que compone la linea mas cercano al punto de comparacion es 
(-58.51164101129704, -34.70237114559549) y la distancia 0.008881956060, cuando lo que necesito es la distancia entre el punto y la linea que une los punto.

Agrego una imagen para que se entienda mejor.

Supongamos que los circulos rojos son los puntos que forman la LineString y el punto negro es al que le debo medir la distancia.

Como se ve en la imagen esta entre dos puntos pero necesito que se mida contra la linea que pinte de color verde, ya que es la mas cercana al punto negro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He pintado la línea a partir de los datos que nos suministras, y el punto en cuestión cuya distancia a la línea quieres conocer. Este es el aspecto (el punto rojo es el que das con coordenadas `(-58.503015,-34.704488)`:

[image: Datos originales]

Como se observa en la figura, el punto que has dado cae de tal manera que la distancia más corta hacia la línea coincide casi con la distancia a un extremo de la línea. La figura siguiente hace un zoom hacia ese extremo, y pinta en verde el punto que has encontrado con tu código (el valor de la variable `np`):

[image: Resultado]

El punto verde cae encima del punto extremo de la curva, por lo que no es un buen ejemplo para determinar si estás calculando la distancia a un punto ya dado, o a la recta que interpola dos puntos.

Probemos en cambio con el punto de coordenadas `(-58.45,-34.68)` que cae más cerca del centro de la curva.

Si, utilizando tu mismo código pero haciendo `Punto` igual al valor que acabo de mencionar, pintamos en rojo el punto y en verde su proyección sobre la curva, vemos que lo que se obtiene es lo que buscabas, la distancia a la recta que une los puntos (pues de hecho `p.distance(linea)` retorna el mismo resultado que `p.distance(np)`, salvo error de redondeo de coma flotante).

Mira:

[image: Resultado]

### Actualización

Este es el código con que he generado los gráficos. Es `matplotlib`, ejecutado en un Jupyter Notebook.

```py
%matplotlib inline

from matplotlib import pyplot
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, LinearRing

# Datos de entrada
Line =  [(-58.39323087479187, -34.64522852285068), (-58.39493519860744, -34.64593911202303), (-58.39540370387294, -34.64612018963881), (-58.39577715270643, -34.64624297063709), (-58.3961720086682, -34.64636735300267), (-58.39657393244798, -34.64649079664271), (-58.39686900560828, -34.64658786576401), (-58.39768408267521, -34.64688376919202), (-58.39804117638568, -34.64699057960223), (-58.39811749931905, -34.64700849164973), (-58.39828903137601, -34.64704378391358), (-58.39848415993365, -34.64708122410398), (-58.3986547387477, -34.64709449060737), (-58.3988514934597, -34.64709955836587), (-58.39897325079004, -34.6471023653607), (-58.39913887311855, -34.64708744614302), (-58.40078230339798, -34.64694668280777), (-58.4011366548087, -34.64692373544752), (-58.40140137506319, -34.64690660901691), (-58.40169294994597, -34.64689298223946), (-58.40188791399491, -34.64691373562576), (-58.40216794959328, -34.64695369573664), (-58.41441599275006, -34.64898345419851), (-58.41468645364731, -34.64902341675737), (-58.41491789917437, -34.6490522244158), (-58.41504783372419, -34.64906712767555), (-58.41517069354625, -34.64908171429391), (-58.41533660567228, -34.64909137548982), (-58.41610344894117, -34.64910924442286), (-58.41663883920926, -34.64911070715178), (-58.41691994816962, -34.64910623905278), (-58.41712925394172, -34.64908282123896), (-58.41735140092969, -34.64905175937751), (-58.4175040105956, -34.64901464682342), (-58.41778163827102, -34.64893890857992), (-58.41810776345819, -34.64882463807892), (-58.42014859446244, -34.64801074189261), (-58.42109129459963, -34.64768468167974), (-58.42150738131538, -34.64755870865789), (-58.42342555778116, -34.64704856595483), (-58.42380036444368, -34.64696522849173), (-58.42402399498763, -34.64692538456899), (-58.42422994553617, -34.64689682578112), (-58.42442882836995, -34.64688048716456), (-58.42466544132492, -34.64686749516407), (-58.42492895224804, -34.64686969903472), (-58.42519118859626, -34.64689581060387), (-58.42548633816839, -34.64693076251233), (-58.42574834123136, -34.64696690278817), (-58.42600734692162, -34.64703299983701), (-58.42633487929256, -34.64713342399471), (-58.42672363380665, -34.6472903832091), (-58.42701863504796, -34.64744017525714), (-58.42735477118806, -34.64764714102999), (-58.42758954729708, -34.64780944247776), (-58.42780426987807, -34.64798874926387), (-58.42805931284784, -34.64825160891823), (-58.42826384085686, -34.64851328718624), (-58.42836837245316, -34.64865441916345), (-58.42849097552769, -34.64886100909527), (-58.42863862000018, -34.64921981114054), (-58.43039902344795, -34.65411150588781), (-58.43058099211167, -34.65454759092934), (-58.43074440690579, -34.65487960245804), (-58.43091147516467, -34.65519055733962), (-58.43112803380347, -34.65554914847827), (-58.43260609566938, -34.65801519415205), (-58.43278567440816, -34.65827265019357), (-58.43296016110701, -34.65845540315134), (-58.43315011877778, -34.65865061801186), (-58.43335842356506, -34.65885169235345), (-58.43349821535271, -34.65894935913921), (-58.43369231539262, -34.65907745659961), (-58.43391244522258, -34.65921105679707), (-58.4342196854351, -34.65939138210857), (-58.43446159367213, -34.65950262175289), (-58.4354319679709, -34.65989668701516), (-58.44002778106239, -34.66183363815986), (-58.44218397209216, -34.66275027310008), (-58.46163757545956, -34.67090968101208), (-58.46246050330255, -34.67120817614321), (-58.46280547898094, -34.67132107658005), (-58.46307488578911, -34.67139608443851), (-58.46332241010779, -34.67144991252323), (-58.46353300409209, -34.67149541798045), (-58.46859653017688, -34.67249959570204), (-58.46908781436287, -34.67259411624501), (-58.46938034898276, -34.67267684368898), (-58.46981999535013, -34.67282189408634), (-58.47017709131737, -34.67296547046871), (-58.47422872212128, -34.67473003403723), (-58.47458907678709, -34.67490463353656), (-58.47485536868304, -34.67507001487545), (-58.47511721636123, -34.67527809815956), (-58.47561611823835, -34.67573966172805), (-58.47637678148585, -34.67650147966764), (-58.4772898411353, -34.677473083393), (-58.47756878106423, -34.67779366716631), (-58.47927838887487, -34.68008637250686), (-58.4796189824651, -34.68046368453628), (-58.4797836819284, -34.68061589623475), (-58.47997298162954, -34.68077149644261), (-58.48013854950542, -34.68087214089938), (-58.48033951807771, -34.68099482470753), (-58.48077178430249, -34.68117907983302), (-58.4809809942354, -34.68125468946911), (-58.48151812211091, -34.68141121492266), (-58.49074865351113, -34.68364996209967), (-58.49280644305118, -34.68416717487745), (-58.49323181266317, -34.68430677581161), (-58.4939040130434, -34.68450404480966), (-58.494446444632, -34.68469758388901), (-58.50679022633284, -34.68987115611775), (-58.50863040256832, -34.6906581855909), (-58.51021336002367, -34.69130911057548), (-58.51092048468821, -34.69162906732615), (-58.51128148474532, -34.69180116103016), (-58.51164513166684, -34.69197626961216), (-58.51190552938787, -34.6921423269721), (-58.51223224913973, -34.6923465503359), (-58.51266317587315, -34.69263696928233), (-58.51283797439013, -34.69275574911642), (-58.51343928772994, -34.69323891435921), (-58.51613617076313, -34.69565149779803), (-58.51639524277449, -34.6959621229764), (-58.51657880735801, -34.69623621532357), (-58.51668736518741, -34.69648714304233), (-58.51677990482248, -34.69677220564932), (-58.51681912473175, -34.69694815217243), (-58.51683540541565, -34.69728978685934), (-58.51682586767205, -34.69757721116119), (-58.51679226699013, -34.697818097686), (-58.51670205772855, -34.69812198637412), (-58.51657448656194, -34.69837726193614), (-58.51643210417134, -34.69861385564264), (-58.51621815101113, -34.69887195886386), (-58.5160233966457, -34.69905049204797), (-58.51546229204164, -34.69948099921363), (-58.51164101129704, -34.70237114559549)]
Punto = (-58.45,-34.68)

# Computar la proyección del punto sobre la línea
line = LineString(Line)
p = Point(Punto)
np = line.interpolate(line.project(p))

# Función para pintar una serie de puntos en el color que se le pase como parámetro
def plot_coords(ax, ob, color='#999999'):
    x, y = ob.xy
    ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color=color, zorder=1)

# Función para pintar una línea (irá superpuesta a los puntos)
def plot_line(ax, ob, color='#6699cc'):
    x, y = ob.xy
    ax.plot(x, y, color=color, alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)

# Creación de la figura con matplotlib
fig = pyplot.figure(1, figsize=(6,6), dpi=90)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Pintar la línea y los puntos que la componen
plot_line(ax, line)
plot_coords(ax, line)

# Pintar en rojo el punto externo y en verde su proyección
plot_coords(ax, p, "red")
plot_coords(ax, np, "green")
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en un momento pondre en practica lo que me respondistes y te contare los resultados, por otro lado me podrias compartir el codigo de los graficos que es una maravilla.

Comment: @Seba79 Actualizada respuesta