# Grafico vacio en Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

estoy replicando este código para graficar una linea y un punto pero cuando intento visualizar el grafico esta vacio.

```
%matplotlib inline

from matplotlib import pyplot
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, LinearRing

# Datos de entrada
Line =  [(-58.39323087479187, -34.64522852285068), (-58.39493519860744, -34.64593911202303), (-58.39540370387294, -34.64612018963881), (-58.39577715270643, -34.64624297063709), (-58.3961720086682, -34.64636735300267), (-58.39657393244798, -34.64649079664271), (-58.39686900560828, -34.64658786576401), (-58.39768408267521, -34.64688376919202), (-58.39804117638568, -34.64699057960223), (-58.39811749931905, -34.64700849164973), (-58.39828903137601, -34.64704378391358), (-58.39848415993365, -34.64708122410398), (-58.3986547387477, -34.64709449060737), (-58.3988514934597, -34.64709955836587), (-58.39897325079004, -34.6471023653607), (-58.39913887311855, -34.64708744614302), (-58.40078230339798, -34.64694668280777), (-58.4011366548087, -34.64692373544752), (-58.40140137506319, -34.64690660901691), (-58.40169294994597, -34.64689298223946), (-58.40188791399491, -34.64691373562576), (-58.40216794959328, -34.64695369573664), (-58.41441599275006, -34.64898345419851), (-58.41468645364731, -34.64902341675737), (-58.41491789917437, -34.6490522244158), (-58.41504783372419, -34.64906712767555), (-58.41517069354625, -34.64908171429391), (-58.41533660567228, -34.64909137548982), (-58.41610344894117, -34.64910924442286), (-58.41663883920926, -34.64911070715178), (-58.41691994816962, -34.64910623905278), (-58.41712925394172, -34.64908282123896), (-58.41735140092969, -34.64905175937751), (-58.4175040105956, -34.64901464682342), (-58.41778163827102, -34.64893890857992), (-58.41810776345819, -34.64882463807892), (-58.42014859446244, -34.64801074189261), (-58.42109129459963, -34.64768468167974), (-58.42150738131538, -34.64755870865789), (-58.42342555778116, -34.64704856595483), (-58.42380036444368, -34.64696522849173), (-58.42402399498763, -34.64692538456899), (-58.42422994553617, -34.64689682578112), (-58.42442882836995, -34.64688048716456), (-58.42466544132492, -34.64686749516407), (-58.42492895224804, -34.64686969903472), (-58.42519118859626, -34.64689581060387), (-58.42548633816839, -34.64693076251233), (-58.42574834123136, -34.64696690278817), (-58.42600734692162, -34.64703299983701), (-58.42633487929256, -34.64713342399471), (-58.42672363380665, -34.6472903832091), (-58.42701863504796, -34.64744017525714), (-58.42735477118806, -34.64764714102999), (-58.42758954729708, -34.64780944247776), (-58.42780426987807, -34.64798874926387), (-58.42805931284784, -34.64825160891823), (-58.42826384085686, -34.64851328718624), (-58.42836837245316, -34.64865441916345), (-58.42849097552769, -34.64886100909527), (-58.42863862000018, -34.64921981114054), (-58.43039902344795, -34.65411150588781), (-58.43058099211167, -34.65454759092934), (-58.43074440690579, -34.65487960245804), (-58.43091147516467, -34.65519055733962), (-58.43112803380347, -34.65554914847827), (-58.43260609566938, -34.65801519415205), (-58.43278567440816, -34.65827265019357), (-58.43296016110701, -34.65845540315134), (-58.43315011877778, -34.65865061801186), (-58.43335842356506, -34.65885169235345), (-58.43349821535271, -34.65894935913921), (-58.43369231539262, -34.65907745659961), (-58.43391244522258, -34.65921105679707), (-58.4342196854351, -34.65939138210857), (-58.43446159367213, -34.65950262175289), (-58.4354319679709, -34.65989668701516), (-58.44002778106239, -34.66183363815986), (-58.44218397209216, -34.66275027310008), (-58.46163757545956, -34.67090968101208), (-58.46246050330255, -34.67120817614321), (-58.46280547898094, -34.67132107658005), (-58.46307488578911, -34.67139608443851), (-58.46332241010779, -34.67144991252323), (-58.46353300409209, -34.67149541798045), (-58.46859653017688, -34.67249959570204), (-58.46908781436287, -34.67259411624501), (-58.46938034898276, -34.67267684368898), (-58.46981999535013, -34.67282189408634), (-58.47017709131737, -34.67296547046871), (-58.47422872212128, -34.67473003403723), (-58.47458907678709, -34.67490463353656), (-58.47485536868304, -34.67507001487545), (-58.47511721636123, -34.67527809815956), (-58.47561611823835, -34.67573966172805), (-58.47637678148585, -34.67650147966764), (-58.4772898411353, -34.677473083393), (-58.47756878106423, -34.67779366716631), (-58.47927838887487, -34.68008637250686), (-58.4796189824651, -34.68046368453628), (-58.4797836819284, -34.68061589623475), (-58.47997298162954, -34.68077149644261), (-58.48013854950542, -34.68087214089938), (-58.48033951807771, -34.68099482470753), (-58.48077178430249, -34.68117907983302), (-58.4809809942354, -34.68125468946911), (-58.48151812211091, -34.68141121492266), (-58.49074865351113, -34.68364996209967), (-58.49280644305118, -34.68416717487745), (-58.49323181266317, -34.68430677581161), (-58.4939040130434, -34.68450404480966), (-58.494446444632, -34.68469758388901), (-58.50679022633284, -34.68987115611775), (-58.50863040256832, -34.6906581855909), (-58.51021336002367, -34.69130911057548), (-58.51092048468821, -34.69162906732615), (-58.51128148474532, -34.69180116103016), (-58.51164513166684, -34.69197626961216), (-58.51190552938787, -34.6921423269721), (-58.51223224913973, -34.6923465503359), (-58.51266317587315, -34.69263696928233), (-58.51283797439013, -34.69275574911642), (-58.51343928772994, -34.69323891435921), (-58.51613617076313, -34.69565149779803), (-58.51639524277449, -34.6959621229764), (-58.51657880735801, -34.69623621532357), (-58.51668736518741, -34.69648714304233), (-58.51677990482248, -34.69677220564932), (-58.51681912473175, -34.69694815217243), (-58.51683540541565, -34.69728978685934), (-58.51682586767205, -34.69757721116119), (-58.51679226699013, -34.697818097686), (-58.51670205772855, -34.69812198637412), (-58.51657448656194, -34.69837726193614), (-58.51643210417134, -34.69861385564264), (-58.51621815101113, -34.69887195886386), (-58.5160233966457, -34.69905049204797), (-58.51546229204164, -34.69948099921363), (-58.51164101129704, -34.70237114559549)]
Punto = (-58.45,-34.68)

# Computar la proyección del punto sobre la línea
line = LineString(Line)
p = Point(Punto)
np = line.interpolate(line.project(p))

# Función para pintar una serie de puntos en el color que se le pase como parámetro
def plot_coords(ax, ob, color='#999999'):
    x, y = ob.xy
    ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color=color, zorder=1)

# Función para pintar una línea (irá superpuesta a los puntos)
def plot_line(ax, ob, color='#6699cc'):
    x, y = ob.xy
    ax.plot(x, y, color=color, alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)

# Creación de la figura con matplotlib
fig = pyplot.figure(1, figsize=(6,6), dpi=90)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Pintar la línea y los puntos que la componen
plot_line(ax, line)
plot_coords(ax, line)

# Pintar en rojo el punto externo y en verde su proyección
plot_coords(ax, p, "red")
plot_coords(ax, np, "green")
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

Imagen del grafico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese código [me suena](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/146200/7123) :-) Acabo de copiarlo y pegarlo tal cual de tu pregunta en un Jupyter Notebook y me sale el gráfico esperado y no vacío como en tu caso. ¿Seguro que tienes instadas las bibliotecas necesarias? ¿Te da algun error la ejecución de la celda?

Comment: jaja, ningun error me da

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código es perfectamente válido y cuando yo lo ejecuto en mi Notebook aparece la gráfica correcta.

Tras conversaciones en privado con el usuario, se descubre finalmente que la causa del problema era la forma en que el código anterior había sido copiado y pegado en el Jupyter Notebook.

He decidido dejar constancia de la solución por si alguien más cae en este mismo error.

El problema era que el usuario había separado en dos celdas diferentes el código que crea la figura:

```
# Creación de la figura con matplotlib
fig = pyplot.figure(1, figsize=(6,6), dpi=90)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

del código que pinta en ella las líneas y puntos:

```
# Pintar la línea y los puntos que la componen
plot_line(ax, line)
plot_coords(ax, line)

# Pintar en rojo el punto externo y en verde su proyección
plot_coords(ax, p, "red")
plot_coords(ax, np, "green")
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

Al separar la ejecución en dos celdas, efectivamente se puede ver el mismo resultado que presenta el usuario. Tras la primera celda, aparece la gráfica vacía y al ejecutar la siguiente ya no aparece nada más.

Esto es debido a la forma en que `matplotlib` opera dentro de Notebook cuando se tiene activo el *backend* `inline`. En ese caso, al final de la celda en la que la figura ha sido creada, se vuelca esa figura y se descarta la variable global `plt` asociada con ella. Por tanto volcamos la figura cuando aún está "a medio hacer".

El problema se resolvió juntando esas dos celdas en una sola.